# как получить данные страницы по токену в javascript?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, token

Всем привет. Пишу свой первый учебный сайт по доставке еды. Сделал страницу регистрации, но хочу, чтобы после регистрации страница переходила на страницу профиля. Для этого после получения токена, делаю еще один запрос на получение данных профиля, заголовок указываю так
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer '+localStorage.getItem('token')); но получаю ошибку origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
Помогите пожалуйста разобраться